# Need help understanding weird replace behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Consider the following code snippet wherein i try to replace a product of two binomial coefficients

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import k, x
a = Wild('a')
b = Wild('b')

pattern = binomial(k,a)*binomial(k,b)
replacement = x

orgineel = binomial(k, 1, evaluate=False)*binomial(k, 1, evaluate=False)
orgineel.replace(pattern , replacement)
```

This returns

[image: Image of failed replacement]

The replacement did not work. However if either one of the binomial coefficients has a different number than 1 it does work! For example, the following code

```py
a = Wild('a')
b = Wild('b')

pattern = binomial(k,a)*binomial(k,b)
replacement = x

orgineel = binomial(k, 1, evaluate=False)*binomial(k, 2, evaluate=False)
orgineel.replace(pattern , replacement)
```

Returns

[image: Image of succesful replacement]

and i don't understand why.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening or how to circumvent it?

For clarity: i know that the first binomial coefficients are simply equal to k, i want to keep them in this form however so i can replace them together with a bunch of other binomials.

Comment: Something to note:
If i change the pattern to `pattern = binomial(k,a)*binomial(k,a)` it does work. Strangely enough, for the case `original=binomial(k,2)*binomial(k,2)` either one works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that is triggered by having an unevaluated expression i.e. `binomial(k, 1, evaluate=False)`. Unevaluated objects like this are difficult to work with in SymPy because many operations will cause them to evaluate implicitly. In this case it is the call to `xreplace` at this line that will trigger evaluation:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/8daad340791cc41707cc1b2b989ce4a9b6c15e75/sympy/core/operations.py#L280

As a workaround you can create your own binomial class that does not evaluate and use that for the replacement:

```py
In [1]: class Binomial(Function):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: k = Symbol('k')
   ...: a = Wild('a')
   ...: b = Wild('b')

In [3]: expr = binomial(k, 1, evaluate=False)**2

In [4]: pattern = binomial(k, a)*binomial(k, b)

In [5]: expr.replace(pattern, x)
Out[5]: 
   2
⎛k⎞ 
⎜ ⎟ 
⎝1⎠ 

In [6]: expr.replace(binomial, Binomial).replace(pattern.replace(binomial, Binomial), x)
Out[6]: x
```

Comment: I opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21842